# Object attributes change when it return from Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given the follow  -

**index.html**

```
var jsonOut = $.getJSON("graph.json", function (jsonIn) {
            console.log(jsonIn);
            return jsonIn;
        });
console.log(jsonOut);
```

**graph.json** - contain a long `JSON` format .

The - `console.log(jsonIn)` output is -

`Object {aaaa: Array[7], bbbb: Array[7], cccc: Array[7]}`

But the - `console.log(jsoOut)` output is -

`Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Why does `jsonIn` and `jsonOut` seems different ? and how could I make jsonOut exactly same as `jsonOut` ?

Comment: You dont `return` from an AJAX request like that -- you pass in a callback and do your work there. One is your response object, the other is `jqXHR` object (I believe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonOut` is the actual ajax object.

You dont need it (Usually ) *inside* the method.

Usually it is used by others who want to do something with this promise object. ( `done` , `fail`, `always` )

In short -  you want `jsonIn`